# Вытащить переменную из многомерного JSON

Tags: php, json, decode

Получаю трёхмерный JSON

```
array(3) {
  ["status"]=>
  string(2) "OK"
  ["status_code"]=>
  int(100)
  ["sms"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["202036-1000001"]=>
            array(6) {
              ["status"]=>
              string(2) "OK"
              ["status_code"]=>
              int(103)
              ["status_text"]=>
              string(39) "Сообщение доставлено"
              ["cost"]=>
              string(5) "12.62"
              ["send_time"]=>
              int(1598945382)
              ["status_time"]=>
              int(1598945602)
            }
      }
}
```

Нужно в переменную забрать $cost=12.62

Никак не соображу, как победить это тройное вложение

Comment: $data['key']['key']['key']['key']...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для обращения к значению массива по ключу следует заключить последний в квадратные скобки

```
$data['key']
```

По этому же принципу можно "добраться" до значений в многомерном массиве

```
$data['key']['key']['key']
```

или в вашем случае

```
$data['sms']['202036-1000001']['cost'];
```

При этом очевидно, что названия ключей можно брать из переменных, например

```
$someKey = '202036-1000001';
$cost = $data['sms'][$someKey]['cost'];
```

Comment: Я пробовал $data[0][0][2] - не работало. А с ключами работает, спасибо.

Comment: 0,0 и 2 - это тоже ключи